# Very Slow Query

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, query-performance

**Problem**

Below is a query I put together in MySQL Workbench that I thought would be relatively simple.  But when running it, on a larger data set (7000+ rows), I find it taking over 200 seconds, uses 1GB of RAM, and downloading data from the MySQL server at a rate of 10+ MB/s that entire time. There isn't 100KB worth of data in the entire table.  So clearly I'm creating some kind of god awful loop here somehow. But I'm not seeing it.

**What I'm doing**

Effectively what this query is doing is taking the specified columns from each row, escaping single and double quotes, then contacting them together into a JSON format exactly as needed for a 3rd party API. After this part of the query is done, I then select the last row, and return it.  (Not seen here it inserts this data into a "cache" table for quick access from the API)

**My Query**

```
set @RowNum := 0;
set @JSON := '';
set @RowTotal := (SELECT count(*) FROM(SELECT * FROM `Job1111`.CivilTrackerDetails GROUP BY BidID) tb);


SELECT (@RowNum := @RowNum + 1) AS ID,   
(@JSON := CONCAT(@JSON, CONCAT(
IF(@RowNum = 1, '[', ''),
'["',
ctd.BidID,
'","', 
REPLACE(REPLACE(ctd.Description, '"', '\\"'),"'", "\\'"), 
'","', 
REPLACE(REPLACE(ctd.FoundationDescription, '"', '\\"'),"'", "\\'"), 
'","', 
REPLACE(REPLACE(ctd.EngDrawingNumber, '"', '\\"'),"'", "\\'"), 
'","', 
REPLACE(REPLACE(ctd.DetailDrawingNumber, '"', '\\"'),"'", "\\'"),  
'","', 
ctd.TakeOffQuantity, 
'"]',
IF(@RowNum = @RowTotal, ']', ',')))) AS JsonData

FROM `Job1111`.CivilTrackerDetails  ctd
```

**Question**

Can you see why this is looping so badly?  Do you know a better way to accomplish this task.  Preferably within the given methodology of arranging the data within MySQL vs out of MySQL.

The explain shows nothing much.. just a derived ctd from a full table scan.  (to be expected).

I'm using version 5.6.3. I have often wondered if some of the JSON compatibility that are supposed to be available in 5.7 may help with this scenario. I have not looked into what is all available in 5.7 yet though. I would be interested in input on that as well.

Ultimately the solution to this issue will be implemented in a stored procedure.

Comment: On your inner select do you really need to return all the columns with *?  Or can you do this query with just one column or id?

Comment: Shawn, My understanding is that using SELECT * is often just as quick as actually specifying a column.  Since SELECT * only uses pointers.  Second Since I'm setting the variable @RowTotal = (Select statement with inner select) I thought that only ran one time.  IF that assumption is correct, that SELECT * should have very insignificant difference on performance.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The `IF(@RowNum = @RowTotal, ...)` seems wrong. One counter (RowNum) goes over the whole table, the other (RowTotal) has counted only the distinct `BidID` values.

Comment: Plus you probably need an `ORDER BY` in the query. See the answer by AndriyM, seems to be in the right direction to solve your issue.

Comment: The `COUNT(*)` does not need the extra layer of `SELECT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me you just need to use the [GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SET @JSON :=
  CONCAT(
    '[',
    (
      SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(
          CONCAT(
            '["', ctd.BidID,
            '","', REPLACE(REPLACE(ctd.Description,           '"', '\\"'),"'", "\\'"), 
            '","', REPLACE(REPLACE(ctd.FoundationDescription, '"', '\\"'),"'", "\\'"), 
            '","', REPLACE(REPLACE(ctd.EngDrawingNumber,      '"', '\\"'),"'", "\\'"), 
            '","', REPLACE(REPLACE(ctd.DetailDrawingNumber,   '"', '\\"'),"'", "\\'"),  
            '","', ctd.TakeOffQuantity, 
            '"]'
          )
          ORDER BY <some-column>
        )
      FROM
        `Job1111`.CivilTrackerDetails AS ctd
    ),
    ']'
  )
;
```

As pointed out by [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james), applying GROUP_CONCAT to an entire table like that might result in exceeding the default [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) value, which is 1024 in MySQL5.7. So, make sure you have set it big enough to accommodate the resulting string by, for instance, setting it session-wise using a SET statement just before the string assignment, like this:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 20480;  -- for example
SET @JSON := ...
```

Answer (score 4):

### MySQL 5.7

Since it's possible for [5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) upgrade, you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) along with [JSON_ARRAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array) which also escapes the inner quotes.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    '[', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      json_array(
        BidID, 
        Description, 
        FoundationDescription, 
        EngDrawingNumber, 
        DetailDrawingNumber, 
        TakeOffQuantity
      )
    ), 
    ']'
  )
FROM
  `Job1111`.CivilTrackerDetails
```

---

### MySQL >= 8.0.1

[JSON_ARRAYAGG](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)

```
SELECT
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    json_array(
      BidID, 
      Description, 
      FoundationDescription, 
      EngDrawingNumber, 
      DetailDrawingNumber, 
      TakeOffQuantity
    )
  )
FROM
  `Job1111`.CivilTrackerDetails
```

Comment: This must certainly be superior going forward.

Comment: I agree, the functionality in 8 looks very promising.. but currently my application runs in Google Cloud SQL.   and it runs version 5.7.  Question, could not the first set of [ ] also be replaced with json_array() in your 5.7 example?  After all we are effectively working with an Array of Arrays here.

Comment: @DarbyM, technically it's an Array of Arrays, but for `json_array` function it's seen as Array of Strings since the result of `GROUP_CONCAT` is just a String rather than of `json` datatype. So if you replace the first set of [] with `json_array`, you would see that the quotes in array is escaped and also each stringArray is quoted wholy. i.e., `["row1value1", "row1value2"], ["row2value1", "row2value2"]` will be produced as `["[\"row1value1\", \"row1value2\"]", "[\"row2value1\", \"row2value2\"]"]` instead of `[["row1value1", "row1value2"], ["row2value1", "row2value2"]]`

Comment: The problem with the last suggestion using JSON_ARRAYAGG and JSON_ARRAY is that those methods are extremely slow compared to GROUP_CONCAT.